# Summing elements of string in Python

Tags: python, string

I am new comer to python. I started to read a book published by MIT's professor about python. I got an exercise from this book. I tried to solve this but i could not.

Problem:  Let s be a string that contains a sequence of decimal numbers
separated by commas, e.g., s = '1.23,2.4,3.123' . Write a program that prints
the sum of the numbers in s.
i have to find out the sum of 1.23,2.4, and 3.123

So far i made some codes to solve this problem and my codes are follwoing:

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
total = 0
for i in s:
    print i
    if i == ',':
```

Please,someone help me how can go further?

Comment: There is always one best way to do it.  Btw, according your description ,  you should compere your old implement with the other:  to group string by comma and then make float, sum .   These changes are more important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is first splitting your string with `,` then you'll have a list of string digits :

```
>>> s.split(',')
['1.23', '2.4', '3.123']
```

Then you need to convert this strings to `float` object till you can calculate those `sum`, for that aim you have 2 choice :

First is using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function :

```
>>> sum(map(float, s.split(',')))
6.753
```

Second way is using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within `sum` function :

```
>>> sum(float(i) for i in s.split(','))
6.753
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative solutions.

Comment: @DumbCoder these are not just alternatives, these are the proper (Pythonic) ways to get your task done. The last one is arguably the most Pythonic one, but both are concise and fast.

Comment: @Eli Korvigo To a new comer that one line  solution is a bit advance but i liked that

Comment: @DumbCoder Not much :) I added the links to references you can read about `map` and `generator expressions`!

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to use `str.split()`, like in

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
total = 0
for i in s.split(','):
    total += float(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much less Pythonic, and more effort, to walk through the string and build up the numbers as you go, but it's probably more in keeping with the spirit of a beginner working things out, and more of a continuation of your original code:

```
s = '1.23,2.4,3.123'
total = 0
number_holder_string = ''

for character in s:
    if character == ',':    # found the end of a number
        number_holder_value = float(number_holder_string)
        total = total + number_holder_value
        number_holder_string = ''

    else:
        number_holder_string = number_holder_string + character

print total
```

That way, number_holder_string goes:

```
''
'1'
'1.'
'1.2'
'1.23'
found a comma -> convert 1.23 from string to value and add it.
''
'2'
'2.'
etc.
```

Comment: You shouldn't really teach a newbie to concatenate strings in Python. This should be replaced by a `str.join` call in a list of accumulated characters.

Comment: Should I also add exception handling in case `float(number_holder_string)` fails?, and explain how `character == ','` is setting a bad habit for languages where assignment is allowed in if tests and missing one equals would lead to a bug? If newbies could learn all the best ways of doing everything, and why, all in one go, there would be no such thing as "a tutorial" for anything, anywhere on the planet. Do string concatenation. It's an exercise for a 14 character string. It's fine.

Comment: this particular method of growing strings is a highly widespread bad habit among newbies that is probably one of the main reasons they think Python is utterly slow. If `float(number_holder_string)` fails he will see an exception, but nothing will tell him that string concatenation harms both time and memory complexity, I hope my point is clear.

Comment: Copy-pasting code we don't understand is another bad habit, though. "Hey newbie who can't count through the characters in a string, wait right there while I tell you about immutable strings, garbage collection, object creation overheads, linked list data structures and why they are more efficient to extend, followed by code you don't understand to avoid a problem you don't understand. Now let's talk about iterating in Python instead of pushing it down the stack like the other answers. Did you follow the generator comprehension OK? Shall we talk about lazy list evaluation now or later?"